# In Plone 4.1.4, using Carousel, border-radius css not persistent in Safari

Tags: webkit, plone, carousel, css

Basically, I would like to have rounded corners on the Carousel on the Home page of a new Plone site. So, in custom.css, I have added the class found from Firebug:

```
.carousel-banners{
-webkit-border-radius: 16px;
-moz-border-radius: 16px;
border-radius: 16px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

In Safari, the first image loads with rounded corners, then all subsequent images lose the rounded corners. There are 5 images, and Carousel is set to 5 seconds on each image with a 0.5 second crossfade transition. Using Carousel 2.2, Plone 4.1.4.

Seems to hold up fine in IE, FF, Chrome, Opera, just is not persistent in Safari. Any ideas?

Comment: For the curious, the carousel JS and CSS can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/collective/Products.Carousel/tree/master/Products/Carousel/browser).